# Dataframe's intersection with itself is smaller than the original DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with approx. 150 million rows (with a single string column).

Here's the minimal code block demonstrating what happens in my application:

```py
df = spark.read.csv("source.csv")
df = df.distinct() # No duplicates!

df1 = df

intersection = df.intersect(df1)
print(df.count(), intersection.count())
# This prints:
# 156203100, 156184232
```

How could this possibly be? Is `df.intersect(df1).count()` not an accurate count?

Additional information:

- `df` is deterministic (no sampling or random values)
- unfortunately, I do not have access to the the actual content of the DataFrame, so I can not look at how the content actually differs.

Comment: Does `intersectAll()` also give the same behaviour?

Comment: Do you use any window function with ordering involved?

Comment: @viggnah `intersectAll()` gives a different count (156197242) - slightly larger than just than the intersect count but not equal to `df.count()`

Comment: @Nithish No window functions are used.